# DOM libraries in .Net for building SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, dom, .net-2.0

### Are there any libraries for .Net for building sql statements?

(BTW I know about ADO.NET SqlCommand, SqlParameter classes already)

I'm currently developing a library to do this but am now wondering if there is already something out there which might be better.

**Edit:**

At this point I'm only interested in returning a DataTable object as I'm developing a reporting feature, hence why I'm not too interested in LINQ (please correct me on this if you think I am misguided).

My main aim is to enable users to select field names for a report from a CheckBoxList and to be able to add/remove filtering expressions (i.e. edit the WHERE clause). Adding fields could mean including sub-selects, not just including a field name in the select clause.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [LINQtoSQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) which is an **relational mapping implementation** that ships in the .NET Framework 3.5 and allows you to model a relational database using .NET classes.

**Edit-**

Since you're using .NET 2.0 With [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx), you'll be able to write local **LINQ to Objects queries** using the full power of the C# 3.0 compiler and yet your programs will require only .NET 2.0.

Comment: I'm limited to .Net 2.0 in this case unfortunately, which rules out LINQ I think. Also, I need to be able to be able to dynamically modify which fields are included in my select statements and what conditions are used in the where clause.

Comment: well LinqtoSQL does only apply to .net 3.5, but it is nice to use in case you ever wanted to upgrade

Comment: @mdresser: you could still use LINQ with LINQBridge by Joe Albahari: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx